# Why My Phone hangs up after app is crashing which I am working on?

Tags: android, thread-safety, fragment

Working on a app which contains a lot of data in the home page like lot of gif images ,maps ,videos and many other things.

The real problem is my app now hangs up almost in every device after app is crashed and then I need to restart device. It's a weird behavior as I don't get any error or exception in the logcat.

How could I resolve the root cause. I have even tried to put less load on main thread but still problem is there.

I have used Services in the app to fetch the data from the server in the background without interrupting user. Is this may the cause ?

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot of help can be offered based on your question.

Possible debugging technique:

1. Use Try catch block, and check for exceptions.
2. Use built in debugger in Android Studio, for step by step traversal.
3. If you are getting information from web, try doing it in background threads.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I tried all these tricks but the issue is any type of crash in the app resulted into unresponsive System ui.

Comment: Okay, these are series of videos explaining how threads work, and UI might be responsive. Might not answer your question quickly, but just for info.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Z5MZ0jL2BM&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE&index=2